# ReactJS / Firebase: Save timestamp field as null value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a material ui date picker field that I want to allow the user to leave blank if not required.

However, ReactJS does not allow me to leave this field as empty or null, as I get the console error of:

> Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value at Date.toISOString

```js
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
  <MobileDatePicker
    label={"Date From"}
    inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
    closeOnSelect={true}
    value={datefrom ?? null}
    minDate={new Date()}
    views={["day"]}
    onChange={(newValue) => {
      setDateFrom(format(newValue, "MM/dd/yyyy"));
      if (dateto == "") {
        setDateTo(format(newValue, "MM/dd/yyyy"));
      }
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField variant="outlined" {...params} fullWidth />
    )}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

How do I force the item to save a timestamp field as empty/null?